# EWS creating Appointment got 401 unauthorized error returned

Tags: exchangewebservices

Anybody knows why I'm getting 401 unauthorized error returned when calling EWS web service URL to create an appointment item? I can get service.AutodiscoverUrl runs fine but when saving appointment item then it error out.

I'm using outlook10, Exchange 2010 and EWS v2.0, here is my code:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myemail", "mypassword", "mydomain.com"); 
    service.Url = new Uri("https://myEWSDomain/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
    service.AutodiscoverUrl("myemail", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback2);

Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
appointment.Subject = "Testing";
appointment.Start = DateTime.Now;
appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(1);
appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("user@test.com");
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
```

any help is greate appreciated.

thanks

Echo